# Starting up a Eureka Docker container. How can we perform a healthcheck on it?

Tags: java, docker

I want to write a `docker-compose` file for my app that has a dependency on Eureka. Here's `Dockerfile` for the app (the app builds fine):

```
FROM amazoncorretto:17-alpine-jdk AS builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN apk add --no-cache maven && \
    mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip=true

FROM amazoncorretto:17-alpine-jdk

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder /app/target/dynamic-gateway-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["java", "-jar", "dynamic-gateway-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

```yaml
version: '2.1'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on: 
      eureka:
        condition: service_healthy
    environment:
      - EUREKA_URL=http://eureka:8761/eureka

  eureka:
    image: springcloud/eureka:latest
    ports:
      - "8761:8761"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl -f http://localhost:8761"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 10
```

```
# the app's properties related to Eureka

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_URL:http://localhost:8761/eureka}
    fetch-registry: true
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true
    non-secure-port-enabled: false
    secure-port-enabled: true
```

I remember when I wrote my own Eureka server (though the entire work was basically adding a Maven dependency in an empty Boot project), I had to include a few properties that turned off Eureka's "self-preservation" mode (see below). Otherwise, it wouldn't start up demanding another Eureka to register with

```yaml
eureka:
  server:
    enable-self-preservation: false
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
```

Based on the logs, it seems I need to do something similar with my Docker Eureka. Below is one of the log messages from Eureka's container. "Cannot execute request on any known server" from my app is a telling sign Eureka didn't start up properly

```
ERROR 1 --- [nio-8761-exec-9] c.n.eureka.resources.StatusResource      : Could not determine if the replica is available
```

The description of Spring Cloud's [official image](https://hub.docker.com/r/springcloud/eureka) (I mean it *looks* official) didn't specify any properties. I tried

```yaml
  eureka:
# ...
    environment:
      - EUREKA.SERVER.ENABLE-SELF-PRESERVATION=false
      - EUREKA.CLIENT.REGISTER-WITH-EUREKA=false
      - EUREKA.CLIENT.FETCH-REGISTRY=false
```

but it didn't work. Though the logs seem to suggest that the "self-preservation" mode *did* turn off

```
dynamic-gateway-eureka-1  | 2024-02-07 14:52:45.657  WARN 1 --- [nio-8761-exec-9] c.n.eureka.PeerAwareInstanceRegistry     : The self preservation mode is disabled!. Hence allowing the instances to expire.                           dynamic-gateway-eureka-1  | 2024-02-07 14:52:56.348 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8761-exec-1] c.n.eureka.resources.StatusResource      : Could not determine if the replica is available                                                            dynamic-gateway-eureka-1  |                                                                                         dynamic-gateway-eureka-1  | java.lang.NullPointerException: null                                                    dynamic-gateway-eureka-1  |     at com.netflix.eureka.resources.StatusResource.isReplicaAvailable(StatusResource.java:90)
```

What is my mistake? Relying on an image updated eight years ago? Or is it some rookie mistake on my part that I can easily fix?

I know I don't include an MRE, but maybe you can just try to run that image and see if it's alright. It's clearly something about that Eureka

Then I changed the Eureka server image

I switched to [my own Eureka own one](https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/nadchel/eureka-server/general) (the one I mentioned above)

```yaml
  eureka:
    image: nadchel/eureka-server:1.0
```

The server now starts up alright, but the healthcheck seems to be misconfigured

```
dynamic-gateway-eureka-1  | 2024-02-07T16:36:57.005Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.n.eureka.DefaultEurekaServerContext    : Initialized                                                               
dynamic-gateway-eureka-1  | 2024-02-07T16:36:57.028Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 1 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'                      
dynamic-gateway-eureka-1  | 2024-02-07T16:36:57.127Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.n.e.s.EurekaServiceRegistry        : Registering application UNKNOWN with eureka with status UP                
dynamic-gateway-eureka-1  | 2024-02-07T16:36:57.174Z  INFO 1 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.c.n.e.server.EurekaServerBootstrap   : isAws returned false                                                      
dynamic-gateway-eureka-1  | 2024-02-07T16:36:57.176Z  INFO 1 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.c.n.e.server.EurekaServerBootstrap   : Initialized server context                                                
dynamic-gateway-eureka-1  | 2024-02-07T16:36:57.177Z  INFO 1 --- [       Thread-9] c.n.e.r.PeerAwareInstanceRegistryImpl    : Got 1 instances from neighboring DS node                                  
dynamic-gateway-eureka-1  | 2024-02-07T16:36:57.180Z  INFO 1 --- [       Thread-9] c.n.e.r.PeerAwareInstanceRegistryImpl    : Renew threshold is: 1                                                     
dynamic-gateway-eureka-1  | 2024-02-07T16:36:57.182Z  INFO 1 --- [       Thread-9] c.n.e.r.PeerAwareInstanceRegistryImpl    : Changing status to UP                                                     
dynamic-gateway-eureka-1  | 2024-02-07T16:36:57.204Z  INFO 1 --- [       Thread-9] e.s.EurekaServerInitializerConfiguration : Started Eureka Server                                                     
dynamic-gateway-eureka-1  | 2024-02-07T16:36:57.225Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8761 (http) with context path ''               
dynamic-gateway-eureka-1  | 2024-02-07T16:36:57.226Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.c.n.e.s.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration : Updating port to 8761                                                     
dynamic-gateway-eureka-1  | 2024-02-07T16:36:57.267Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.e.e.EurekaServerApplication            : Started EurekaServerApplication in 8.865 seconds (process running for 10.635)                                                                                                 
dynamic-gateway-eureka-1  | 2024-02-07T16:37:57.185Z  INFO 1 --- [a-EvictionTimer] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Running the evict task with compensationTime 0ms                          
dependency failed to start: container dynamic-gateway-eureka-1 is unhealthy
```

Does that "curl"-based healthcheck really a good one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`curl` didn't work because it wasn't installed inside the Eureka image. I updated the image like this so now it works:

```
FROM amazoncorretto:17-alpine-jdk AS builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN apk add --no-cache maven && \
    mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip=true

FROM amazoncorretto:17-alpine-jdk

RUN apk add --no-cache curl

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder /app/target/EurekaServer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar .

EXPOSE 8761

CMD ["java", "-jar", "EurekaServer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

As long as the Eureka server is running on the same machine as a service that tries to connect to it (even if it's not dockerized at all), connection by `localhost` still works fine (I checked)

As for why the official Eureka image didn't work, *that* I don't know